# Cannot delete a record from MS Access specifically of the type "TEXT"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, delete-row

I am trying to delete a record on the basis of my primary key `tid` from `MS Access` of the DataType `TEXT`.But the problem is, it doesn't get deleted.Where as there is no problem deleting a field of DataType `int`.Any reasons? the field `tid` is my primary key.

I made a mistake by making it of the type `TEXT`, now would like to convert it to `int` (in programmatic way) ? Without making changes to MS Access DB and bind it again?

Ask for the code if required.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

**EDIT as requested by @Scotch :**
This is the code snip giving me problems.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim delcmd As New OleDbCommand("delete from teacher where tid=" & TextBox1.Text & " ", conaccess)
        delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Record is deleted")
        loadGrid()
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()

        loadGrid()
    End Sub
```

Were as, other insert operations are running just fine:

Example:

```
   Dim access As String = String.Format("INSERT INTO teacher (tid,tname,dept,type) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')", TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, ComboBox2.Text, ComboBox1.Text)
    concmd.Connection = conaccess
    concmd.CommandText = access
    concmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Record Successfully Saved")
    loadGrid()
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
```

Comment: What do you mean the record isn't being deleted? Are you trying to delete the `field` tid or are you trying to delete a record based on it's `tid`

Comment: Can you right-click it first and turn off primary key, then delete it?

Comment: @Scotch oh my Bad! i mean the record based on `tid`.Will make an edit.Thanks.

Comment: No problem. So are you running some vb code that is something like `"delete FROM myTable where tid ='" & myvar & "';"` ?

Comment: @Scotch yes, should i edit it?

Comment: @cardmagik don't i have to bind it again?

Comment: Yup, add your code please -we'll be able to help you better

Comment: Do you have any foreign key constraints? perhaps it's not working because of that  and you're not receiving the message because of JET. Try to delete the row manually through Access and see if it tells you that you can't because related records blablahblah

Comment: @Scotch  "Do you have any foreign key constraints?" no.At present i don't have any foreign key of the current table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your tid field is `text`, you need quotes in your delete statement.

```
  Dim delcmd As New OleDbCommand("delete from teacher where tid='" & TextBox1.Text & "'", conaccess)
```

If you want to change the field type to a number, you can do that. It will warn you, but if you just have numeric characters in every record's tid field, it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you.Will try and let you know.

Comment: Yup, I thinkkk that will fix it, no promises though.

Comment: Thank you very much.Working perfect.So simple mistake! Gosh!! Thanks!!:)Don't have Enough rept. to give you a +1, But still Thanks:)

Comment: No problem, I make mistakes like that all the time :). There's some good guys here on the Access sub, so if you run into problems, help isn't far away.